# multiple browser with same input file

Tags: amazon-s3, architecture, ftp, aws-lambda, web-deployment

an input text file from the web browser needs to be processed in AWS lambda and the output (JSON) needs to rendered back to the browser. (note: AWS beanstalk is being used).
How to handle a case, if there are 10 users/client uploading text file with the same name. AWS lambda should render the output to the respective user/client. How to do this with S3 or EFS.
(NOTE: the users cannot be uniquely identified as there any login credentials for the users)

Comment: Would it be ok for you to append a random number to the filenames? This would make name collisions very unlikely. If you'd like to avoid any possibility of collision, store an auto-increment ID in a database and append it to the filenames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had similar problem and solved in the following way.
Find the uniqueness and name it accordingly.

> Filename-TimeStamp.Extension

If there are frequent uploads in a given time, then add a random sequence number.

> Filename-TimeStamp-RandomSequence.Extension

If you want to make it completely random, you can use uuid(hexadecimal) or idgen (alphanumeric)

Hope this help.